# what is meaning of two ranking columns shown in "last 30 days" and "All Time" at topusers section?

Tags: support, top-users

What is meaning of two ranking columns shown in "last 30 days" and "All Time"  at  topusers section ?

For example : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-s3/topusers

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left column is the total score, the right one is the total number of answers.

Hovering with the mouse on it reveals the secret:

[image: When in doubt, hover!]

Comment: True. "when in doubt, hover" - learned this rule in a very early stage. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard well said :) I changed the description of the image to your quote..

Comment: haha! actually you just changed the "alt" text showing when image fails to load or in text readers, I edited to make it the image title.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not me, it's the Coffee that I still didn't have.

Comment: lol, actually I suspect very few knows how to add titles to images using markdown. I learned it after long years only...